# Como restringir solo numeros en un prompt?

Tags: javascript, condiciones

estoy aprendiendo javascript.
Intento hacer un ejercicio que mediante un prompt me pida numeros y los inserte en un array.
Pero quiero validar que SOLO se inserten numeros, si se mete algo ! de numero me mande un alert.
Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
var ejercicio_arreglo=[];
var añadir_numero="";

do{     
    añadir_numero= parseInt(prompt("Introduce el numero"));
    ejercicio_arreglo.push(añadir_numero);
}
while(añadir_numero != "00") {  //esto hasta que se introduzca doble 0 terminara de añadir
alert("terminaste de añadir");
}
document.write(ejercicio_arreglo);
```

Quiero meter un IF para decir que si es NaN, me arroje el alert, pero no me funciona. O mas bien no se en donde incrustar el IF dentro del codigo. Ya que donde lo meta, me arroja el alerta inmediatamente.

```
if(isNaN(añadir_numero)|| añadir_numero<0 || añadir_numero!=""){
alert("Solo numeros!!!");
}
```

Gcs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola jose seguramente estabas poniendo el if al principio y siempre se te iba a ejecutar valido el `isNan` porque es su valor inicial de echo (''),
te dejo donde lo agregue para que funcione y para que completes las otras validaciones que necesites , el while del final ademas solo contempla la condicion para que el bucle del do siga ejecutandose asi que te saque el cuerpo {} que tenias que seria la siguiente linea de codigo a mostrar , en este caso el alert que finaliza la carga , espero te sirva saludos!

```js
var ejercicio_arreglo=[];
var añadir_numero="";

do{     
    
    añadir_numero= parseInt(prompt("Introduce el numero"));
    if(isNaN(añadir_numero))
    {alert('solo numeros!')}
    else{

        ejercicio_arreglo.push(añadir_numero);

    }
}
while(añadir_numero != "00")   //esto hasta que se introduzca doble 0 terminara de añadir
alert("terminaste de añadir");
 
console.log(ejercicio_arreglo);
```

Comment: En este caso la linea: 
 isNaN(añadir_numero)|| añadir_numero<0 || añadir_numero!="") no es necesario usarse asi como lo tengo? con || <0 || =" "   ?

Comment: Otra duda es..... en el while  lo tenia asi......while(añadir_numero != "00"){
alert("terminaste de añadir");
}   y veo que le eliminaste las llaves. No son necesarias? ya que al ejecutarlo conllaves funciona bien

Comment: claro jose por eso te deje el comentario para que las agregues si es lo que necesitas , si es que necesitas el numero sea >mayor a 0 o que no sea un string vacio ''.Lo del while no es necesario porque estas usando el do-while y la estructura es asi : do { //aca va el codigo } while(condicion)....